# Get user information from MySQL in modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Basically what I have is user list table with 1 side Email and other side actions.
One of the actions is Delete, which is this code:

Button:

```
<button type="button" class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_DELETE" data-whatever="<?php echo $sub["adminEmail"]; ?>"> <span class="fa fa-times"> </span> </button><a> </a>
```

Modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_DELETE" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal_nameDELETE">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="modal_nameDELETE">Delete confirmation</h4>
</div>
<form method="post">
<div class="modal-body">
Are you sure you want to remove user:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" disabled>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="idx" name="email_to_remove">
<br>    
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="delete">Yes</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#modal_DELETE').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var recipient = button.data('whatever');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);


});
});
</script>
```

But now I have problem with edit because I want to do some PHP code.
Basically it would say users permission but you could edit it.
Like this:

```
<?php
$permissions = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sub_permission WHERE id_bota=:id");
$permissions->bindParam(":id",$ID);
$permissions->execute();
$pInfo = $permissions->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
    <label><h4>Changing connection info</h4> 
        <select input style="width:200px; overflow:hide;" type="text" name="config_connectionInfo" class="form-control">
            <?php if($pInfo["config_connectionInfo"] == 1){ ?>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="0">No</option>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>

            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </label>
```

I have this in a form but I just dont know how could I pass the email to the MySQL select query. Then in the modal it would display all permissions and if the permission is assigned it would say 
    Yes
    No
or if its not assigned
    No
    Yes

Comment: I'd recommend you go searching for `ajax` calls, and research the topic well!

Comment: @Babydead - Why do you even comment if its not gonna help -.-"

Comment: I commented to point you in the right direction. Because now you will get answers you do not understand. It **is** helping. Look at it: You just commented on your own question with "Why isn't this working?" (next time edit your question itself)... this is to be expected if you get answers but don't understand them. If you research ajax calls yourself, you will have a better understanding of how what works and the answers given will make sense, and work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put an ajax request in your code to interact with php.

```
$(function(){
$('#modal_DELETE').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var recipient = button.data('whatever');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'phpScript.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
           //Your data
        }
    }).done(function(response){
        //PHP end execution
    });

});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I sent you a link on ajax usage, RTFM